# Ожидание завершения функции в цикле

Tags: javascript

Приветствую. Столкнулся с проблемой ожидания завершения функции.

Код вызывается на каждый элемент массива:

```
domain_json.forEach(function(item, i) {

    // какие-то действия

    setTimeout(function(){
        getnextredirect(item);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Выполнение этой функции может занять до минуты.

```
function getnextredirect(domainname) {
    // какие-то действия, если условия не выполнены функция
    // вызывает сама себя, что-бы дождаться выполнения условий
    setTimeout(function(){getnextredirect(domainname)}, 5000);
}
```

Как указать скрипту, что-бы он дождался завершения работы функции и потом перешагнул на следующий элемент в each?

Comment: не вызывать функцию внутри `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` не будет ждать асинхронного `setTimout`

Могу предложить использовать следующую конструкцию

```js
flag = false;

domains = ['localhost', 'wetGrundy.com', 'overflow.com'];

(function each(n) {

    // какие-то действия
 
    getNextRedir(domains[n], next);
    function next() { n++; if(n < domains.length) each(n); }

})(0);

function getNextRedir(domain, next) {
 
    // какие-то действия, что-бы дождаться выполнения условий
 
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(domain);
  
        if(flag) {
            flag = false;
            next();
        } else { // если условия не выполнены
            getNextRedir(domain, next); // функция вызывает сама себя
        }
 
    }, 1000);
}

function setFlag() {
    flag = true;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='setFlag()'>Какие-то действия</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то можно использовать promise-объекты, вот пример на основе вашего:

```js
var domain_json = [ "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4" ];

domain_json.forEach(function(item, i) {
  // какие-то действия
  getnextredirect(item).then(function(data){
  //какие-то действия по завершению работы функции
    alert(data);
  });
});

function getnextredirect(domainname) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  // какие-то действия, при которых выполняется условие 
  setTimeout(function(){
     d.resolve(domainname);
  }, 100);
  
  return d.promise();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Кто мне пояснит, за что минус?

Comment: например не гарантируется очередность выполнения: _дождался завершения работы функции и потом перешагнул на следующий элемент в each?_